# Gridsearch on an experiment in Sacred

Tags: python, machine-learning, folium, mlflow, python-sacred

I'm trying to see some ways to store my ML experiments and I came across some python libraries like Sacred, ModelChimp, MLFlow, ....

The one I like the most is Sacred, but I would like to know how to save the `GridSearchCV` sklearn object the way ModelChimp does, for example. Is there any way to include each of the tests that the `GridSearchCV` object does in Sacred like ModelChimp does?

Additionally I would like to be able to visualize an interactive map of the folium library (which I would simply export to HTML), but I haven't seen that any of these libraries accept objects to visualize beyond an image.

Are Sacred or ModelChimp good options? The little I've seen of MLflow or other libraries hasn't convinced me either but I'm open to suggestions. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/bx0apm/d_how_do_you_manage_your_machine_learning/) are a few more alternatives. Which one do you use?